# Debugging C++ on VSCode MacOS: Module containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the breakpoint address could not be obtained

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, debugging, lldb

I have got three files: 
main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "log.h"

int main()
{
    int a = 8; // Breakpoint on this line
    a++;
    const char *string = "Hello";

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        const char c = string[i];
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
    }

    Log("Hello, World!");
    std::cin.get();
}
```

log.cpp

```cpp
#include "log.h"

#include <iostream>

void Log(const char* message)
{
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

log.h

```cpp
#pragma once

void Log(const char* message);
```

My launch.json looks like this:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

The output in the terminal is:

```
H
e
l
l
o
Hello, World!
```

When I debug using the VSCode debugger, the breakpoint shows a white circle and upon hovering on it the following is displayed: "Module containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the breakpoint address could not be obtained". I'm new to the language and debugging and cannot figure out what to do based on the solutions to similar questions on the internet. Please help, Thanks!

Comment: Does the program itself run though? Like, you see the log message in the terminal/debug output?

Comment: @Wutz yes it does. I'll edit in the output to the question.

Comment: What happens when you start debugging? Does the program stop at `main()`? Can you use step over/step into buttons?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that worked for me and is allowing me to move forward with debugging is to go to the launch.json file and change the "program" to the path the file you're trying to debug is. 
So in my case,

```json
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/cpp/main.cpp"
```

Comment: "program" should be an executable file, setting it to your C++ source file won't do any good.

Comment: you're right. I changed by launch.json back and it still works fine. I don't know how that happened. I think the problem might be with the permissions. When debugging , MacOS asks whether you'd like to let main access a particular folder, you just have to allow that I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a lack of debugging information in your program, an issue solved by adding debugging flags when compiling (often, a `-g` flag, see the [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) and [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-debug-information) manuals).

Instructing the compiler to add debugging information to the program enables the debugger (in your case lldb) to do various things, such as setting breakpoints in the source code.

If simply adding `-g` to your compile flags doesn't solve the issue, VSCode's [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp#_how-do-i-enable-debug-symbols) on debug symbols could be of help.